Private Store Members does not work for class-based SignalStore in NgRx version 18
In ngrx/signals 17.2.0 I could have private store members in class-based SignalStore but that does not seem to work in version 18.1.1
import { computed, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { patchState, signalStore, withState } from '@ngrx/signals';

@Injectable()
export class CounterStore extends signalStore({ protectedState: false }, withState({ count: 0, _privateMember: 0 })) {
  readonly doubleCount = computed(() => this.count() * 2);

  increment(): void {
    patchState(this, { count: this.count() + 1, _privateMember: this._privateMember() + 1 });
  }
}

Gives error:
TS2339: Property _privateMember does not exist on type CounterStore
